# Is there a way to disable only root login via serial console on RHEL6?

Tags: linux, rhel, login, root, console

I'm trying to disable root login via the serial console in RHEL 6.  Based on this link from redhat (https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/html/Security_Guide/s2-wstation-privileges-noroot.html), it says to basically clear out the `/etc/securetty` file.  So, I have done that, and it does disable root login.  The problem is that it disables ALL login.  I still need to access it with a non-root login.
   So, is there a way to disable root login via console, yet still be able to login with other users.  For example, with ssh, you can modify the `"PermitRootLogin yes/no"` parameter to do this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean disabling root password? So that you can't login with `root` either in a console or in UI (which is a terrible idea)?

There are plenty of question about that : [disable root login on console](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/350502/disable-root-login-on-console)

But the casual solution is:

```
sudo passwd -l root
```

This is RHEL compatible since it is a very basic and old command.

But be careful to have `sudo` rights on other user accounts or you won't be able to run commands with root credentials anymore.

Comment: No, the questioner really does mean what xe says in the question: preventing the `root` account from logging on from that terminal (or, in this case, any other).  This is what the _secure TTY_ mechanism mentioned in the question and the referenced instructions from RedHat is all about.

Comment: Yes, just want to prevent root from logging in, but allow all other accounts access.  After following the instructions, I cannot login with any account, let alone root.